# showing an indexed table in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json with a few rows like this:

```
{{"0":"94122","1":"94132","2":"94131","3":"94116","4":"94107"}
{"0":4,"1":2,"2":4,"3":2,"4":2}}
```

When I call this:

```
  <li ng-repeat="x in table">
  {{ x }}
   </li>
```

I get:

```
 {"0":"94122","1":"94132","2":"94131","3":"94116","4":"94107"}
 {"0":4,"1":2,"2":4,"3":2,"4":2}
```

How do I get it to display this as a table like this:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="roll in sushi">
    <td>{{ roll.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ roll.fish }}</td>
    <td>{{ roll.tastiness }}</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in table">
    <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in x">{{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

or

```
 <tr ng-repeat="x in table">
    <td>
        <p ng-repeat="(key, value) in x">{{value}}</p>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

or

```
 <tr ng-repeat="x in table">
    <td>
        <ul>    
            <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in x">{{value}}</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: how would I make it list horizontal instead of vertical?

Comment: What do you mean by horizontal? The tds are new columns in the table

Comment: I mean how would I make the columns into rows.

Comment: Right now each of these values would be in the same row. If you want all of the values to appear vertically in their own rows, then you would either need to create one table cell with values as their own <p> tags or use an unordered list with values as an <li>

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this?

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in table">
    <td>{{ x["0"] }}</td>
    <td>{{ x["1"] }}</td>
    <td>{{ x["2"] }}</td>
    <td>{{ x["3"] }}</td>
    <td>{{ x["4"] }}</td>
  </tr>
```